# Поддерживается ли java 8 в андроиде ниже 7?

Tags: java, android

Андроид поддерживает java 8 добавлением в gradle suporta 1.8 .Но это действительно для андроид 7.0 и если я там использую лямбды то на телефонах с прошивкой 4.0+ приложение будет падать?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поддержка/не поддержка Java 8 не зависит от версии Android.

Напомню как устроена компиляция в Android:

```
.java -> .class -> .dex
```

Java 8 работает только на этапе компиляции Java исходников в объектники `.class`, далее вступает в действие утилита dex, которая JVM объектник переводит в Dalvik/ART объектник - `.dex`. Так что как только у вас есть `.class` - уже не играет роли из чего он был создан из Java 8 или 7, 6. Были бы портированы библиотеки, остальное уже не играет роли.

**Update**

По следам дискуссии в комментариях акцентирую - новинки Java 8 условно можно разделить на новые фичи самого языка и новые методы API (библиотечные функции).

Так вот: фичи языка (как явствует из логики ответа) не зависят от версии Android. Другое дело с фичи API - их наличие/отсутствие целиком и полностью зависит от их портирования на Android. В основном они доступны только в API 24.

Comment: тем не менее, из java 8 на всех версиях андроид поддерживаются только лямбды (из значимого). С API 24 - стримы и еще несколько фич (смотрите по ссылке под вопросом полный список), многое из java 8 вообще не доступно.

Comment: стримы это библиотечная история, а не фичи самого языка, так что это просто означает, что стрим библиотеки не портированы в dex

Comment: тем не менее, это значит, что на версиях ниже API24 стримы работать не будут, а это возможность, заявленная в Java 8. Ясно, что нет разницы, какую версию Java использовать, если компилируемый код не использует новое API из Java 8, но абсолютное большинство нововведений, сделанных в Java 8 не доступно ниже API24, а некоторые из них - недоступно вообще в android

Comment: Есть фичи языка есть библиотечные новинки. В вопросе речь шла о лямбдах - фичах языка. К тому же в моем ответе есть сноска: *Были бы портированы библиотеки, остальное уже не играет роли*